# Assigning function invocation to anonymous field in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am returning anonymous type from my linq query:

```
select new {
Exists = true,
Code = new Func<string,string>((string param) => {
                                      if (param == "T")
                                          return "Tab";
                                      if (param == "E")
                                          return "Eub";
                                      if (param == "C")
                                          return "GTW";
                                      if (param == "X")
                                          return "XUX";
                                      return "";
}
}
```

An error:

> A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

is being thrown but it does not tell me anything.

**Question:** How to handle that without creating new nonanonymous function?

Comment: It's telling you that you can't use code blocks inside expressions. Code block are the `if` /`return` statements inside `{` `}` after `=>`.

Comment: Why use a select statement to get a lambda?

Comment: @IvanStoev How to handle that without creating new nonanonymous function?

Answer (score 0):

Why use `Func<string,string>`?

```
something.Select(x => new {
Exists = true,
Code = x.param == "T" ? "Tab" :
       x.param == "E" ? "Eub" :
       x.param == "C" ? "GTW" :
       x.param == "X" ? "XUX" : ""
});
```

Comment: And from whence does `param` come from then?

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not looks nice :(

Comment: where it was coming before?

Comment: param comes from linq query

Comment: @justme why doesn't it look nice? it is faster, more readable, shorter,...

Comment: OP returns function in Code property, this example returns value.

Comment: Oh, he wants to assign a function to a variable?